# Why does settimeout cause a 502 in my aws lambda?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, async-await, settimeout

Running on node 10.x lambda.  If I remove the delay promise all my fetch calls work as expected. Logging the fetch callbacks result in nothing.  The timeout seemingly just stops the lambda. Am I missing something?  Perhaps how lambdas run nodeJS is unique?

The following is a simplified version of my code.

```
import fetch from "node-fetch";

const delay = (ms: number) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

export const handler = async (): Promise<any> => {
    try {
        const publishedEvents = [
            'event 1',
            'event 2',
            'event 3'
        ]

        for (const publishEvent of publishedEvents) {
          await fetch('url', { method: 'POST', body: publishEvent });
          await delay(60000);
        }

        return {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: 'Published all Events'
        };
    } catch (e) {
        return {
            statusCode: 400,
            body: 'Failed Call'
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Maybe your lambda function's timeout is shorter than your delay? Have you adjusted it?

Comment: @Marcin This is what I get for working until 8am... Thank you for pointing out the obvious to me. Dear oh deary me.

Comment: No problem. I will make answer for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was that lambda function's [execution timeout](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-function.html#cfn-lambda-function-timeout) was too short. The solution was to increase it.